# How to integrate cron job in this simple php framework?

Tags: php, cron

I am using this simple php framework/strukture https://github.com/panique/mini

I want to integrate a cron job and call it from my cpanel.

I really have no idea how it should be done but since I already have a working database connection with the existing model, I think that could create a new php file in the model directory.

The model folder can not be accessed directly from the browser (because of the framework structure) but can it reached from a cron job?

I have tested with a simple insert which does not work.

New file structure

```
application
----model
    ----model.php
    ----cron.php
```

cron.php

```
class Cron
{
    function __construct($db)
    {
      try {
          $this->db = $db;
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          exit('Database connection could not be established.');
      }
      $this->deleteSong();
    }

public function deleteSong()
    {
       $song_id = 1;

        $sql = "DELETE FROM song WHERE id = :song_id";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = array(':song_id' => $song_id);

        $query->execute($parameters);
    }
}
```

And this in cron jobs -> command

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/myUsername/public_html/application/model/cron.php
```

No cron jobs mail (which works) and no error.

Comment: In more advanced frameworks you have a dedicated cronjob option. To be honest, I'm not familiar with `mini framework` but if there's not a built-in option i'll recommend the following: Use a regular controller which is accessible via the browser **but** in your php code request a parameter, let's say `secret` and have a condition the check its value (which is only known to you). Sound good?